# Align image in center

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to align my img in center, but not happens with this code:

```
<div id="foto" style="position:relative; left:50%;">
    <img src="Imgs/pa1.PNG" width="160" height="240" alt="foto1" />
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center it within the body or within the div?

Comment: By aligning, you mean vertical and horizontal or only horizontal?

Answer (score 3):

Use `text-align:`

```
<div id="foto" style="text-align: center;">
   <img src="Imgs/pa1.PNG" width="160" height="240" alt="foto1">
</div>
```

Comment: ` <div class="panel" title="port" data-nav="nav_0" id="page_0" selected="selected" style="">
    <div id="foto" style="text-align: center !important;">
    <img src="Imgs/pa1.PNG" width="160" height="240" alt="foto">
    </div>
    <br> some text.
 </div>` 
not happens :S

Comment: Working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NHXMy/

Comment: Maybe it IS centered but the container is no wider than the img. You can test this by setting the width of #foto to > 160

Comment: Do you trying this ? http://jsfiddle.net/skwZy/2/

Comment: If you want the text also aligning center then you must make sure it is inside the div with the text-align property

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?

Answer (score 2):

Dont use inline style. See this **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/skwZy/)** 
If you give outer div `text-align:center;` then all your text in your div will align in center. So its not a good practice.

```
<div id="foto">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" width="160" height="240" alt="foto1">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#foto {
    width: 100%;
}
#foto img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below css.

```
img {
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

or

```
#foto {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#foto
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1000px;//give width accordingly 

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="foto" >
   <img src="Imgs/pa1.PNG" width="160" height="240" alt="foto1">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With an image I feel you can simply apply the css rule "text-align: center;"

But if thats not working for you could try taking out the position rules and giving the "foto" div a width and an auto margin like so:

```
style="width:960px; margin: 0 auto;"
```

I am also not sure if you are aware of style sheets but seperating your CSS from your HTML is also good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Make CSS as

```
div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EHAVul/1)